# Position a dropdown to a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I would like a dropdown to position to a specific value(current year/month) when the user clicks on the dropdown.  In the case below lets say the current month is 2020-03. Do you know the JS I would use to position on click to the value of 2020-03?

```
  <select id="month_due"   onclick = "$(document).ready(()=>{$('#month_due').val('2020-03');}); " tabindex="8" name="month_due">
   <option value = " "> &nbsp</option>
   <option value = "2020-01">Jan 20</option>
   <option value = "2020-02">Feb 20</option>
   <option value = "2020-03">March 20</option>
   <option value = "2020-04">April 20</option>
   <option value = "2020-05">May 20</option>
   <option value = "2020-06">June 20</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail if one is to understand what you need :)

Comment: May I suggest concentrating on JavaScript before getting lost in jquery?
Please add jquery to tags of question (so people like me, who don't care for jquery, can filter questions like this out).
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javascript code to select an option is by using `value` of the `select` tag:

```
document.getElementById("month_due").value = "2020-03";
```

The way you can choose the current month is by using `Date` in javascript, and put it in a string (the string will be used to the value). It will be like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var txt = ""; // the string
txt += d.getFullYear(); // get a 4 digits year (2020)
txt += "-";
var month = d.getMonth() + 1; // adding 1 because the first month (Jan) is 0
if (month < 10)
{
  txt += "0"; // so it will be "03" and not only "3"
}
txt += month;
```

Then, the `txt` will have `"2020-03"` as a string. And then you can use the function:

```
document.getElementById("month_due").value = txt;
```